# Panda Dataframe : Grouping by from column's values, while creating columns for each of another column's values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sorry if the title is not clear i'm a newbie, hopefully an exemple will make it more understandable.
So let's take this DataFrame :

```
Area     AorB     Population

Hah      A         23
Hah      B         8
Hah      C         78
Ryu      A         150
Ryu      B         61
Ryu      C         17
```

I'd like to create a dataframe which would have a column with the 2 Areas, 3 columns named Apop, Bpop and Cpop and the corresponding population. It should look like that :

```
Area     Apop   Bpop   Cpop

Hah      23     8      78
Ryu      150    61     17
```

It might sounds dumb but i've been searching for hours how to do this D: help.

Answer (score 1):

Let us try

```
out = df.pivot(*df).add_suffix('pop').reset_index()

Out[8]: 
AorB Area  Apop  Bpop  Cpop
0     Hah    23     8    78
1     Ryu   150    61    17
```

Comment: it unpacks the columns names:
print(*df)
Area AorB Population
so each one fits into the three pivot parameters

Answer (score 1):

Another way;

```
df.set_index(['Area','AorB']).unstack().reset_index().droplevel(0, axis=1).add_suffix('pop') 

AorB  pop  Apop  Bpop  Cpop
0     Hah    23     8    78
1     Ryu   150    61    17
```